# How to add a column to the left of a datafra,e

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I am trying to add a column to the left of the dataframe. By default it seems to add to the right. Is there a way to add the columns to the left?

Here is my code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.read_csv("/home/Sample Text Files/sample5.csv", delimiter = "\t")
df=pd.DataFrame(df)
df['Creation_DT']=pd.to_datetime('today')
print(df)
```

Here is the output:

```
 ID,Name,Age                Creation_DT
0  1233,Maliva,15 2019-07-17 11:11:37.145194
```

I want the output to be like this:

```
Creation_DT, ID, Name, Age
[value], [Value], [Value], [Value]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can add a line of code to rearrange the columns as follows:

```
df = df[['Creation_DT', 'ID', 'Name', 'Age']]
```

another option is to insert the column during conversion:

```
df.insert(loc=0, column='Creation_DT', value=pd.to_datetime('today'))
```

Answer (score 2):

try [df.insert](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.insert.html) to place column at specific data

```
df.insert(loc=0, column='Creation_DT', value=pd.to_datetime('today'))
```